# Migration of AWS Pod library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Currently i'm using AWS and AWSCore in my project which supports upto swift 2.0. Now i want to migrate to swift 3.0. is AWS pod support for swift 3.0 is available?

Comment: I have used AWS 2.5.5 and its support Swift 3.0 please try that one for your project.

Answer (score 0):

yes it supports swift 3. I am developing my project in swift 3 and use AWS sdk version 2.5.2 and everything works fine. The latest sdk version is 2.5.5. Try converting your project to swift 3 and if you face any error then update your AWS sdk to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience you have to upgrade it as mention here :

AWS Lib version for Sift 3.0 is **2.5.5** which is latest one.

**Github Link :** https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios

**Pod :** https://cocoapods.org/pods/AWSCore

Do as directed and every thing works with Swift 3.0.

Hope this will helps!